# How to create a 3D matrix with third dimension equal one in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to create a 3D matrix of (MxNx1) dimension. where third dimension is equal to 1.
I am trying something like zeros(M,N,1) but it is returning a matrix of (MxN) dimension instead of (MxNx1) dimension. Is there any way of creating a 3D matrix where third dimension equal to 1.

Comment: AFAIK, it's because trailing singleton dimensions are skipped for display purposes. What do you intend to do anyway with creating `MxNx1` matrix?

Comment: Ok, I have written a function. where I send images of dimension(MxN). I normally send (MxNxD) matrix where D is the number of images. since my code assume matrix is 3D. I can't use it for single image of (MxN).Since I can't make it (MxNx1).

Comment: How is your code checking if the input matrix is 3D or not?

Comment: Divakar's last comment should be useful for you, as the singleton dimension do exist (although not shown) and you can check for them, for instance m=rand(3,4); size(m,3) will show you 1. So, the third dimension is equal to 1 already.

Comment: @Shahidul - If your question is solved, consider adding an answer yourself and accepting it, so as to avoid confusion.

Comment: Is doesn't help that `ndims(zeros(2,3,1)) == 2` and that `size(1,3) == 1`.  MATLAB thinks `zeros(2,3,1)` has 2 dimensions but that `1` has 3! This makes is difficult to check a variable with dimensions [L,M,N], where N itself could vary in the code and sometimes be equal to 1.

Answer (score 0):

How do you process a MxNxD image? I could only image that the useage of the third dimension is:

```
[M,N,D] = size(your3DMatrix);
```

Then you use D for further coding. Another possible useage is

```
permute(your3DMatrix,[n1 n2 n3])
```

Anyway, these both work fine for matrix whose third dimension is 1.

If you detail your code dealing with the MxNx1 matrix, it would be easier to help you.